# Zentralblatt MATH volume numbering

Tags: soft-question, gm.general-mathematics, mathscinet, zbmath, msc

Recently, I learned how to read some of codes that appear on specific pages in zbMATH Open, formerly known as Zentralblatt MATH.
[image: example book review]

For example, in the above review, the circled code "Zbl 1218.47001" signifies that the review belongs to Volume 1218 of Zentralblatt MATH, that the book under review primarily falls under Subject 47 (Operator theory) in the Mathematics Subject Classification, and that the review is the first (#001) review in this Volume under this Subject. (Source: [EMIS page](http://emis.mi.sanu.ac.rs/ZMATH/zmath/en/help/search), the entry for "accession number".)

For bibliographic purposes, I'd like to know: How does the Zentralblatt MATH volume numbering work? In particular, how can we find the publication year of the review, given the Zentralblatt MATH volume number? For example, Zentralblatt MATH volume number 980 was published in the year 2002. (Sources: [1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1441928901), [2](https://zbmath.org/0980.41025).)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thank you for asking! As mentioned, the structure of the ID is Zbl xxxx.yyyyy, but it has changed its semantic once after the introduction of the MSC.

The first number indicates the volume (starting with Vol. 1 in 1931), the second is connected to the MSC since its introduction in Vol. 218. Since then, the structure is in fact xxxx.yyzzz - yy indicating the main MSC, zzz indicating the numbering in this section.

For Volume 1-217, the semantics is actually xxxx.yyyzz - yyy the page number of the volume, zz the number of the review on that page.

Concerning the publication years, the issue is somewhat complicated. Since Vol. 1050 (vol. 1/2005), there are 25 annual volumes. Before that, there were mostly 24 annual volumes and additional index volumes (which contained just meta-information, no entries/reviews).

Therefore, the index volumes in the database (which has obviously its own index) are missing, e.g., vol. 1000 (which was the last index volume). The frequency of the index volumes was first every ten volumes, then 25.

For some old volumes (especially post-war, where some gap volumes collected publications which were missed earlier), the situation is even not completely clear, since there is some conflicting information in the printed volumes (this is the main reason why these figures are not yet displayed in the database). Especially, Vol. 59-63 appeared out of the regular schedule with several issues from 1965-1978(!).

I add the following table for orientation (note that some information is unclear, since some printed volumes contain conflicting information, especially for the "gap volumes"). Due to limitations (full table is too large), the table ends with vol. 723 (1991); after that, it is pretty straightforward, 724-749 (1992), and then 25 vol/year, with index volumes 730, 740, 750, 775, 800, 825, 850, 875, 900, 925, 950, 975, and 1000.

| Vol | Year | Issue | Remark |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1931 | 1 |  |
| 1 | 1931 | 2 |  |
| 1 | 1931 | 3 |  |
| 1 | 1931 | 4 |  |
| 1 | 1931 | 5 |  |
| 1 | 1931 | 6 |  |
| 1 | 1931 | 7 |  |
| 1 | 1931 | 8 | Index issue |
| 2 | 1932 | 1 |  |
| 2 | 1932 | 2 |  |
| 2 | 1932 | 3 |  |
| 2 | 1932 | 4 |  |
| 2 | 1932 | 5 |  |
| 2 | 1932 | 6 |  |
| 2 | 1932 | 7 |  |
| 2 | 1932 | 8 | Index issue |
| 3 | 1932 | 1 |  |
| 3 | 1932 | 2 |  |
| 3 | 1932 | 3 |  |
| 3 | 1932 | 4 |  |
| 3 | 1932 | 5 |  |
| 3 | 1932 | 6 |  |
| 3 | 1932 | 7 |  |
| 3 | 1932 | 8 |  |
| 3 | 1932 | 9 |  |
| 3 | 1932 | 10 | Index issue |
| 4 | 1932 | 1 |  |
| 4 | 1932 | 2 |  |
| 4 | 1932 | 3 |  |
| 4 | 1932 | 4 |  |
| 4 | 1932 | 5 |  |
| 4 | 1932 | 6 |  |
| 4 | 1932 | 7 |  |
| 4 | 1932 | 8 |  |
| 4 | 1932 | 9 |  |
| 4 | 1932 | 10 | Index issue |
| 5 | 1933 | 1 |  |
| 5 | 1933 | 2 |  |
| 5 | 1933 | 3 |  |
| 5 | 1933 | 4 |  |
| 5 | 1933 | 5 |  |
| 5 | 1933 | 6 |  |
| 5 | 1933 | 7 |  |
| 5 | 1933 | 8 |  |
| 5 | 1933 | 9 |  |
| 5 | 1933 | 10 | Index issue |
| 6 | 1933 | 1 |  |
| 6 | 1933 | 2 |  |
| 6 | 1933 | 3 |  |
| 6 | 1933 | 4 |  |
| 6 | 1933 | 5 |  |
| 6 | 1933 | 6 |  |
| 6 | 1933 | 7 |  |
| 6 | 1933 | 8 |  |
| 6 | 1933 | 9 |  |
| 6 | 1933 | 10 | Index issue |
| 7 | 1934 | 1 |  |
| 7 | 1934 | 2 |  |
| 7 | 1934 | 3 |  |
| 7 | 1934 | 4 |  |
| 7 | 1934 | 5 |  |
| 7 | 1934 | 6 |  |
| 7 | 1934 | 7 |  |
| 7 | 1934 | 8 |  |
| 7 | 1934 | 9 |  |
| 7 | 1934 | 10 | Index issue |
| 8 | 1934 | 1 |  |
| 8 | 1934 | 2 |  |
| 8 | 1934 | 3 |  |
| 8 | 1934 | 4 |  |
| 8 | 1934 | 5 |  |
| 8 | 1934 | 6 |  |
| 8 | 1934 | 7 |  |
| 8 | 1934 | 8 |  |
| 8 | 1934 | 9 |  |
| 8 | 1934 | 10 | Index issue |
| 9 | 1934 | 1 |  |
| 9 | 1934 | 2 |  |
| 9 | 1934 | 3 |  |
| 9 | 1934 | 4 |  |
| 9 | 1934 | 5 |  |
| 9 | 1934 | 6 |  |
| 9 | 1934 | 7 |  |
| 9 | 1934 | 8 |  |
| 9 | 1934 | 9 |  |
| 9 | 1934 | 10 | Index issue |
| 10 | 1935 | 1 |  |
| 10 | 1935 | 2 |  |
| 10 | 1935 | 3 |  |
| 10 | 1935 | 4 |  |
| 10 | 1935 | 5 |  |
| 10 | 1935 | 6 |  |
| 10 | 1935 | 7 |  |
| 10 | 1935 | 8 |  |
| 10 | 1935 | 9 |  |
| 10 | 1935 | 10 | Index issue |
| 11 | 1935 | 1 |  |
| 11 | 1935 | 2 |  |
| 11 | 1935 | 3 |  |
| 11 | 1935 | 4 |  |
| 11 | 1935 | 5 |  |
| 11 | 1935 | 6 |  |
| 11 | 1935 | 7 |  |
| 11 | 1935 | 8 |  |
| 11 | 1935 | 9 |  |
| 11 | 1935 | 10 | Index issue |
| 12 | 1936 | 1 |  |
| 12 | 1936 | 2 |  |
| 12 | 1936 | 3 |  |
| 12 | 1936 | 4 |  |
| 12 | 1936 | 5 |  |
| 12 | 1936 | 6 |  |
| 12 | 1936 | 7 |  |
| 12 | 1936 | 8 |  |
| 12 | 1936 | 9 |  |
| 12 | 1936 | 10 | Index issue |
| 13 | 1936 | 1 |  |
| 13 | 1936 | 2 |  |
| 13 | 1936 | 3 |  |
| 13 | 1936 | 4 |  |
| 13 | 1936 | 5 |  |
| 13 | 1936 | 6 |  |
| 13 | 1936 | 7 |  |
| 13 | 1936 | 8 |  |
| 13 | 1936 | 9 |  |
| 13 | 1936 | 10 | Index issue |
| 14 | 1936 | 1 |  |
| 14 | 1936 | 2 |  |
| 14 | 1936 | 3 |  |
| 14 | 1936 | 4 |  |
| 14 | 1936 | 5 |  |
| 14 | 1936 | 6 |  |
| 14 | 1936 | 7 |  |
| 14 | 1936 | 8 |  |
| 14 | 1936 | 9 |  |
| 14 | 1936 | 10 | Index issue |
| 15 | 1937 | 1 |  |
| 15 | 1937 | 2 |  |
| 15 | 1937 | 3 |  |
| 15 | 1937 | 4 |  |
| 15 | 1937 | 5 |  |
| 15 | 1937 | 6 |  |
| 15 | 1937 | 7 |  |
| 15 | 1937 | 8 |  |
| 15 | 1937 | 9 |  |
| 15 | 1937 | 10 | Index issue |
| 16 | 1937 | 1 |  |
| 16 | 1937 | 2 |  |
| 16 | 1937 | 3 |  |
| 16 | 1937 | 4 |  |
| 16 | 1937 | 5 |  |
| 16 | 1937 | 6 |  |
| 16 | 1937 | 7 |  |
| 16 | 1937 | 8 |  |
| 16 | 1937 | 9 |  |
| 16 | 1937 | 10 | Index issue |
| 17 | 1937 | 1 |  |
| 17 | 1937 | 2 |  |
| 17 | 1937 | 3 |  |
| 17 | 1938 | 4 |  |
| 17 | 1938 | 5 |  |
| 17 | 1938 | 6 |  |
| 17 | 1938 | 7 |  |
| 17 | 1938 | 8 |  |
| 17 | 1938 | 9 |  |
| 17 | 1938 | 10 | Index issue |
| 18 | 1938 | 1 |  |
| 18 | 1938 | 2 |  |
| 18 | 1938 | 3 |  |
| 18 | 1938 | 4 |  |
| 18 | 1938 | 5 |  |
| 18 | 1938 | 6 |  |
| 18 | 1938 | 7 |  |
| 18 | 1938 | 8 |  |
| 18 | 1938 | 9 |  |
| 18 | 1938 | 10 | Index issue |
| 19 | 1938 | 1 |  |
| 19 | 1938 | 2 |  |
| 19 | 1938 | 3 |  |
| 19 | 1938 | 4 |  |
| 19 | 1939 | 5 |  |
| 19 | 1939 | 6 |  |
| 19 | 1939 | 7 |  |
| 19 | 1939 | 8 |  |
| 19 | 1939 | 9 |  |
| 19 | 1939 | 10 | Index issue |
| 20 | 1939 | 1 |  |
| 20 | 1939 | 2 |  |
| 20 | 1939 | 3 |  |
| 20 | 1939 | 4 |  |
| 20 | 1939 | 5 |  |
| 20 | 1939 | 6 |  |
| 20 | 1939 | 7 |  |
| 20 | 1939 | 8 |  |
| 20 | 1939 | 9 |  |
| 20 | 1939 | 10 | Index issue |
| 21 | 1939 | 1 |  |
| 21 | 1939 | 2 |  |
| 21 | 1939 | 3 |  |
| 21 | 1939 | 4 |  |
| 21 | 1939 | 5 |  |
| 21 | 1939 | 6 |  |
| 21 | 1939 | 7 |  |
| 21 | 1940 | 8 |  |
| 21 | 1940 | 9 |  |
| 21 | 1940 | 10 | Index issue |
| 22 | 1940 | 1 |  |
| 22 | 1940 | 2 |  |
| 22 | 1940 | 3 |  |
| 22 | 1940 | 4 |  |
| 22 | 1940 | 5 |  |
| 22 | 1940 | 6 |  |
| 22 | 1940 | 7 |  |
| 22 | 1940 | 8 |  |
| 22 | 1940 | 9 |  |
| 22 | 1940 | 10 | Index issue |
| 23 | 1940 | 1 |  |
| 23 | 1940 | 2 |  |
| 23 | 1940 | 3 |  |
| 23 | 1940 | 4 |  |
| 23 | 1940 | 5 |  |
| 23 | 1940 | 6 |  |
| 23 | 1941 | 7 |  |
| 23 | 1941 | 8 |  |
| 23 | 1941 | 9 |  |
| 23 | 1941 | 10 | Index issue |
| 24 | 1941 | 1 |  |
| 24 | 1941 | 2 |  |
| 24 | 1941 | 3 |  |
| 24 | 1941 | 4 |  |
| 24 | 1941 | 5 |  |
| 24 | 1941 | 6 |  |
| 24 | 1941 | 7 |  |
| 24 | 1941 | 8 |  |
| 24 | 1941 | 9 |  |
| 24 | 1941 | 10 | Index issue |
| 25 | 1941 | 1 |  |
| 25 | 1941 | 2 |  |
| 25 | 1941 | 3 |  |
| 25 | 1941 | 4 |  |
| 25 | 1941 | 5 |  |
| 25 | 1942 | 6 |  |
| 25 | 1942 | 7 |  |
| 25 | 1942 | 8 |  |
| 25 | 1942 | 9 |  |
| 25 | 1942 | 10 | Index issue |
| 26 | 1942 | 1 |  |
| 26 | 1942 | 2 |  |
| 26 | 1942 | 3 |  |
| 26 | 1942 | 4 |  |
| 26 | 1942 | 5 |  |
| 26 | 1942 | 6 |  |
| 26 | 1942 | 7 |  |
| 26 | 1942 | 8 |  |
| 26 | 1942 | 9 |  |
| 26 | 1943 | 10 | Index issue |
| 27 | 1943 | 1 |  |
| 27 | 1943 | 2 |  |
| 27 | 1943 | 3 |  |
| 27 | 1943 | 4 |  |
| 27 | 1943 | 5 |  |
| 27 | 1943 | 6 |  |
| 27 | 1943 | 7 |  |
| 27 | 1943 | 8 |  |
| 27 | 1943 | 9 |  |
| 27 | 1943 | 10 | Index issue |
| 28 | 1943 | 1 |  |
| 28 | 1943 | 2 |  |
| 28 | 1943 | 3 |  |
| 28 | 1944 | 4 |  |
| 28 | 1944 | 5 |  |
| 28 | 1944 | 6 |  |
| 28 | 1944 | 7 |  |
| 28 | 1944 | 8 |  |
| 28 | 1944 | 9 |  |
| 28 | 1944 | 10 | Index issue |
| 29 | 1948 | 1 – 2 |  |
| 29 | 1948 | 3 – 4 |  |
| 29 | 1948 | 5 |  |
| 29 | 1948 | 6 |  |
| 29 | 1948 | 7 |  |
| 29 | 1948 | 8 |  |
| 29 | 1948 | 9 |  |
| 29 | 1948 | 10 | Index issue |
| 30 | 1949 | 1 |  |
| 30 | 1949 | 2 |  |
| 30 | 1949 | 3 |  |
| 30 | 1949 | 4 |  |
| 30 | 1949 | 5 |  |
| 30 | 1949 | 6 |  |
| 30 | 1949 | 7 |  |
| 30 | 1949 | 8 |  |
| 30 | 1949 | 9 |  |
| 30 | 1949 | 10 | Index issue |
| 31 | 1949 | 1 |  |
| 31 | 1949 | 2 |  |
| 31 | 1949 | 3 |  |
| 31 | 1949 | 4 |  |
| 31 | 1949 | 5 |  |
| 31 | 1949 | 6 |  |
| 31 | 1949 | 7 |  |
| 31 | 1949 | 8 |  |
| 31 | 1949 | 9 |  |
| 31 | 1949 | 10 | Index issue |
| 32 | 1949 | 1 |  |
| 32 | 1949 | 2 |  |
| 32 | 1950 | 3 |  |
| 32 | 1950 | 4 |  |
| 32 | 1950 | 5 |  |
| 32 | 1950 | 6 |  |
| 32 | 1950 | 7 |  |
| 32 | 1950 | 8 |  |
| 32 | 1950 | 9 |  |
| 32 | 1949 | 10 | Index issue, year likely misprint? |
| 33 | 1950 | 1 |  |
| 33 | 1950 | 2 |  |
| 33 | 1950 | 3 |  |
| 33 | 1950 | 4 – 5 |  |
| 33 | 1950 | 6 – 7 |  |
| 33 | 1950 | 8 – 9 |  |
| 33 | 1950 | 10 | Index issue |
| 34 | 1950 | 1 – 3 |  |
| 34 | 1950 | 4 – 6 |  |
| 34 | 1950 | 7 – 9 |  |
| 34 | 1950 | 10 | Index issue |
| 35 | 1950 | 1 – 3 |  |
| 35 | 1950 | 4 – 6 |  |
| 35 | 1950 | 7 – 9 |  |
| 35 | 1950 | 10 | Index issue |
| 36 | 1951 | 1 – 3 |  |
| 36 | 1951 | 4 – 6 |  |
| 36 | 1951 | 7 – 9 |  |
| 36 | 1951 | 10 | Index issue |
| 37 | 1951 | 1 – 3 |  |
| 37 | 1951 | 4 – 6 |  |
| 37 | 1951 | 7 – 9 | Index issue |
| 37 | 1951 | 10 |  |
| 38 | 1951 | 1 – 3 |  |
| 38 | 1951 | 4 – 9 |  |
| 38 | 1951 | 10 | Index issue |
| 39 | 1951 | 1 – 5 |  |
| 39 | 1951 | 6 – 9 |  |
| 39 | 1951 | 10 |  |
| 40 | 1951 | 1 – 3 |  |
| 40 | 1951 | 4 – 6 |  |
| 40 | 1951 | 7 – 9 |  |
| 40 | 1951 | 10 |  |
| 41 | 1952 | 1 – 3 |  |
| 41 | 1952 | 4 – 7 |  |
| 41 | 1953 | 8 – 12 |  |
| 41 | 1952 | 13 |  |
| 42 | 1952 | 1 – 5 |  |
| 42 | 1952 | 6 – 10 |  |
| 43 | 1952 | 1 – 5 |  |
| 43 | 1952 | 6 – 10 |  |
| 44 | 1952 | 1 – 5 |  |
| 44 | 1952 | 6 – 10 |  |
| 45 | 1955 | 1 – 3 | year likely misprint? |
| 45 | 1953 | 4 – 6 |  |
| 45 | 1955 | 7 – 10 |  |
| 46 | 1953 | 1 – 5 |  |
| 46 | 1953 | 6 – 10 |  |
| 47 | 1953 | 1 – 5 |  |
| 47 | 1953 | 6 – 10 |  |
| 48 | 1953 | 1 – 5 |  |
| 48 | 1953 | 6 – 10 |  |
| 49 | 1954 | 1 – 3 |  |
| 49 | 1955 | 4 – 6 |  |
| 49 | 1959 | 7 | year likely misprint? |
| 50 | 1954 | 1 – 5 |  |
| 50 | 1954 | 6 – 10 |  |
| 51 | 1954 | 1 – 5 |  |
| 51 | 1954 | 6 – 10 |  |
| 52 | 1955 | 1 – 5 |  |
| 52 | 1955 | 6 – 10 |  |
| 53 | 1956/1961 | 1 – 4 | Conflicting information in Print |
| 53 | 1957 | 5 |  |
| 53 | 1961 | 6 |  |
| 54 | 1951-1961 |  |  |
| 55 | 1955 | 1 – 5 |  |
| 55 | 1955 | 6 – 10 |  |
| 56 | 1955 | 1 – 5 |  |
| 56 | 1955 | 6 – 10 |  |
| 57 | 1956 | 1 – 5 |  |
| 57 | 1956 | 6 |  |
| 58 | 1958 | 1 |  |
| 58 | 1958 | 2 |  |
| 59 | 1965-1966 |  | GAP volume |
| 60 | 1957 |  | GAP volume |
| 61 | 1961 |  | GAP volume |
| 62 | 1974 |  | GAP volume |
| 63 | 1976-1978 |  | GAP volume |
| 64 | 1956 | 1 – 5 |  |
| 64 | 1956 | 6 – 10 |  |
| 65 | 1956 | 1 |  |
| 65 | 1956 | 2 |  |
| 66 | 1957 | 1 |  |
| 66 | 1957 | 2 |  |
| 67 | 1958 | 1 |  |
| 67 | 1958 | 2 |  |
| 68 | 1961 | 1 |  |
| 68 | 1961 | 2 |  |
| 69 | 1957-1964 |  | GAP volume |
| 70 | 1957 | 1 |  |
| 70 | 1957 | 2 |  |
| 71 | 1958 | 1 |  |
| 71 | 1958 | 2 |  |
| 72 | 1958 | 1 |  |
| 72 | 1958 | 2 |  |
| 73 | 1959 | 1 |  |
| 73 | 1960 | 2 |  |
| 74 | 1960 | 1 |  |
| 74 | 1962 | 2 |  |
| 75 | 1968/71 | 1 |  |
| 75 | 1971/73 | 2 |  |
| 76 |  |  |  |
| 77 | 1958 | 1 |  |
| 77 | 1958 | 2 |  |
| 78 | 1959 | 1 |  |
| 78 | 1959 | 2 |  |
| 79 | 1959 | 1 |  |
| 79 | 1959 | 2 |  |
| 80 | 1959 | 1 |  |
| 80 | 1959 | 2 |  |
| 81 | 1959 | 1 |  |
| 81 | 1959 | 2 |  |
| 82 | 1960 | 1 |  |
| 82 | 1960 | 2 |  |
| 83 | 1960 | 1 |  |
| 83 | 1960 | 2 |  |
| 84 | 1960 | 1 |  |
| 84 | 1960 | 2 |  |
| 85 | 1961 | 1 |  |
| 85 | 1961 | 2 |  |
| 86 | 1961 | 1 |  |
| 86 | 1961 | 2 |  |
| 87 | 1961 | 1 |  |
| 87 | 1961 | 2 |  |
| 88 | 1961 | 1 |  |
| 88 | 1961 | 2 |  |
| 89 | 1961 | 1 |  |
| 89 | 1961 | 2 |  |
| 90 | 1961 | 1 |  |
| 90 | 1961 | 2 |  |
| 91 | 1962 | 1 |  |
| 91 | 1962 | 2 |  |
| 92 | 1962 | 1 |  |
| 92 | 1962 | 2 |  |
| 93 | 1962 | 1 |  |
| 93 | 1962 | 2 |  |
| 94 | 1962 | 1 |  |
| 94 | 1962 | 2 |  |
| 95 | 1962 | 1 |  |
| 95 | 1962 | 2 |  |
| 96 | 1962 | 1 |  |
| 96 | 1962 | 2 |  |
| 97 | 1962 | 1 |  |
| 97 | 1962 | 2 |  |
| 98 | 1963 | 1 |  |
| 98 | 1963 | 2 |  |
| 99 | 1963 | 1 |  |
| 99 | 1963 | 2 |  |
| 100 | 1963 | 1 |  |
| 100 | 1963 | 2 |  |
| 101 | 1963 | 1 |  |
| 101 | 1963 | 2 |  |
| 102 | 1963 | 1 |  |
| 102 | 1963 | 2 |  |
| 103 | 1964 | 1 |  |
| 103 | 1964 | 2 |  |
| 104 | 1964 | 1 |  |
| 104 | 1964 | 2 |  |
| 105 | 1964 | 1 |  |
| 105 | 1964 | 2 |  |
| 106 | 1964 | 1 |  |
| 106 | 1964 | 2 |  |
| 107 | 1964 | 1 |  |
| 107 | 1964 | 2 |  |
| 108 | 1964 | 1 |  |
| 108 | 1964 | 2 |  |
| 109 | 1964 | 1 |  |
| 109 | 1965 | 2 |  |
| 110 | 1965 |  | Index volume |
| 111 | 1964 | 1 |  |
| 111 | 1965 | 2 |  |
| 112 | 1965 | 1 |  |
| 112 | 1965 | 2 |  |
| 113 | 1965 | 1 |  |
| 113 | 1965 | 2 |  |
| 114 | 1965 | 1 |  |
| 114 | 1965 | 2 |  |
| 115 | 1965 | 1 |  |
| 115 | 1965 | 2 |  |
| 116 | 1965 | 1 |  |
| 116 | 1965 | 2 |  |
| 117 | 1965 | 1 |  |
| 117 | 1965 | 2 |  |
| 118 | 1965 | 1 |  |
| 118 | 1966 | 2 |  |
| 119 | 1966 | 1 |  |
| 119 | 1966 | 2 |  |
| 120 | 1966 |  | Index volume |
| 121 | 1966 | 1 |  |
| 121 | 1966 | 2 |  |
| 122 | 1966 | 1 |  |
| 122 | 1966 | 2 |  |
| 123 | 1966 | 1 |  |
| 123 | 1966 | 2 |  |
| 124 | 1966 | 1 |  |
| 124 | 1966 | 2 |  |
| 125 | 1966 | 1 |  |
| 125 | 1966 | 2 |  |
| 126 | 1966 | 1 |  |
| 126 | 1967 | 2 |  |
| 127 | 1967 | 1 |  |
| 127 | 1967 | 2 |  |
| 128 | 1967 | 1 |  |
| 128 | 1967 | 2 |  |
| 129 | 1967 | 1 |  |
| 129 | 1967 | 2 |  |
| 130 | 1967 |  | Index volume |
| 131 | 1967 | 1 |  |
| 131 | 1967 | 2 |  |
| 132 | 1967 | 1 |  |
| 132 | 1967 | 2 |  |
| 133 | 1967 | 1 |  |
| 133 | 1967 | 2 |  |
| 134 | 1967 | 1 |  |
| 134 | 1967 | 2 |  |
| 135 | 1967 | 1 |  |
| 135 | 1967 | 2 |  |
| 136 | 1967 | 1 |  |
| 136 | 1967 | 2 |  |
| 137 | 1967 | 1 |  |
| 137 | 1967 | 2 |  |
| 138 | 1967 | 1 |  |
| 138 | 1967 | 2 |  |
| 139 | 1968 | 1 |  |
| 139 | 1968 | 2 |  |
| 140 | 1968 |  | Index volume |
| 141 | 1968 | 1 |  |
| 141 | 1968 | 2 |  |
| 142 | 1968 | 1 |  |
| 142 | 1968 | 2 |  |
| 143 | 1968 | 1 |  |
| 143 | 1968 | 2 |  |
| 144 | 1968 | 1 |  |
| 144 | 1968 | 2 |  |
| 145 | 1968 | 1 |  |
| 145 | 1968 | 2 |  |
| 146 | 1968 | 1 |  |
| 146 | 1968 | 2 |  |
| 147 | 1968 | 1 |  |
| 147 | 1968 | 2 |  |
| 148 | 1968 | 1 |  |
| 148 | 1968 | 2 |  |
| 149 | 1968 | 1 |  |
| 149 | 1968 | 2 |  |
| 150 | 1968 |  | Index volume |
| 151 | 1968 |  |  |
| 152 | 1968 | 1 |  |
| 152 | 1968 | 2 |  |
| 153 | 1968 | 1 |  |
| 153 | 1968 | 2 |  |
| 154 | 1968 | 1 |  |
| 154 | 1968 | 2 |  |
| 155 | 1968 | 1 |  |
| 155 | 1968 | 2 |  |
| 156 | 1969 | 1 |  |
| 156 | 1969 | 2 |  |
| 157 | 1969 | 1 |  |
| 157 | 1969 | 2 |  |
| 158 | 1969 | 1 |  |
| 158 | 1969 | 2 |  |
| 159 | 1969 | 1 |  |
| 159 | 1969 | 2 |  |
| 160 | 1969 |  | Index volume |
| 161 | 1969 | 1 |  |
| 161 | 1969 | 2 |  |
| 162 | 1969 | 1 |  |
| 162 | 1969 | 2 |  |
| 163 | 1969 | 1 |  |
| 163 | 1969 | 2 |  |
| 164 | 1969 | 1 |  |
| 164 | 1969 | 2 |  |
| 165 | 1969 | 1 |  |
| 165 | 1969 | 2 |  |
| 166 | 1969 | 1 |  |
| 166 | 1969 | 2 |  |
| 167 | 1969 | 1 |  |
| 167 | 1969 | 2 |  |
| 168 | 1969 | 1 |  |
| 168 | 1969 | 2 |  |
| 169 | 1969 | 1 |  |
| 169 | 1969 | 2 |  |
| 170 | 1969 |  | Index volume |
| 171 | 1969 | 1 |  |
| 171 | 1969 | 2 |  |
| 172 | 1969 | 1 |  |
| 172 | 1969 | 2 |  |
| 173 | 1969 | 1 |  |
| 173 | 1969 | 2 |  |
| 174 | 1969 | 1 |  |
| 174 | 1969 | 2 |  |
| 175 | 1969 | 1 |  |
| 175 | 1969 | 2 |  |
| 176 | 1969 | 1 |  |
| 176 | 1969 | 2 |  |
| 177 | 1970 | 1 |  |
| 177 | 1970 | 2 |  |
| 178 | 1970 | 1 |  |
| 178 | 1970 | 2 |  |
| 179 | 1970 | 1 |  |
| 179 | 1970 | 2 |  |
| 180 | 1970 |  | Index volume |
| 181 | 1970 | 1 |  |
| 181 | 1970 | 2 |  |
| 182 | 1970 | 1 |  |
| 182 | 1970 | 2 |  |
| 183 | 1970 | 1 |  |
| 183 | 1970 | 2 |  |
| 184 | 1970 | 1 |  |
| 184 | 1970 | 2 |  |
| 185 | 1970 | 1 |  |
| 185 | 1970 | 2 |  |
| 186 | 1970 | 1 |  |
| 186 | 1970 | 2 |  |
| 187 | 1970 | 1 |  |
| 187 | 1970 | 2 |  |
| 188 | 1970 | 1 |  |
| 188 | 1970 | 2 |  |
| 189 | 1970 | 1 |  |
| 189 | 1970 | 2 |  |
| 190 | 1970 |  | Index volume |
| 191 | 1970 | 1 |  |
| 191 | 1970 | 2 |  |
| 192 | 1970 | 1 |  |
| 192 | 1970 | 2 |  |
| 193 | 1970 | 1 |  |
| 193 | 1970 | 2 |  |
| 194 | 1970 | 1 |  |
| 194 | 1970 | 2 |  |
| 195 | 1970 | 1 |  |
| 195 | 1970 | 2 |  |
| 196 | 1970 | 1 |  |
| 196 | 1970 | 2 |  |
| 197 | 1971 | 1 |  |
| 197 | 1971 | 2 |  |
| 198 | 1971 | 1 |  |
| 198 | 1971 | 2 |  |
| 199 | 1971 | 1 |  |
| 199 | 1971 | 2 |  |
| 200 | 1971 |  | Index volume |
| 201 | 1971 | 1 |  |
| 201 | 1971 | 2 |  |
| 202 | 1971 | 1 |  |
| 202 | 1971 | 2 |  |
| 203 | 1971 | 1 |  |
| 203 | 1971 | 2 |  |
| 204 | 1971 | 1 |  |
| 204 | 1971 | 2 |  |
| 205 | 1971 | 1 |  |
| 205 | 1971 | 2 |  |
| 206 | 1971 | 1 |  |
| 206 | 1971 | 2 |  |
| 207 | 1971 | 1 |  |
| 207 | 1971 | 2 |  |
| 208 | 1971 | 1 |  |
| 208 | 1971 | 2 |  |
| 209 | 1971 | 1 |  |
| 209 | 1971 | 2 |  |
| 210 | 1971 |  | Index volume |
| 211 | 1971 | 1 |  |
| 211 | 1971 | 2 |  |
| 212 | 1971 | 1 |  |
| 212 | 1971 | 2 |  |
| 213 | 1971 | 1 |  |
| 213 | 1971 | 2 |  |
| 214 | 1971 | 1 |  |
| 214 | 1971 | 2 |  |
| 215 | 1971 | 1 |  |
| 215 | 1971 | 2 |  |
| 216 | 1971 | 1 |  |
| 216 | 1971 | 2 |  |
| 217 | 1972 | 1 |  |
| 217 | 1972 | 2 |  |
| 218 | 1972 |  |  |
| 219 | 1972 |  |  |
| 220 | 1972 |  | Index volume |
| 221 | 1972 |  |  |
| 222 | 1972 |  |  |
| 223 | 1972 |  |  |
| 224 | 1972 |  |  |
| 225 | 1972 |  |  |
| 226 | 1972 |  |  |
| 227 | 1972 |  |  |
| 228 | 1972 |  |  |
| 229 | 1972 |  |  |
| 230 | 1972 |  | Index volume |
| 231 | 1972 |  |  |
| 232 | 1972 |  |  |
| 233 | 1972 |  |  |
| 234 | 1972 |  |  |
| 235 | 1972 |  |  |
| 236 | 1972 |  |  |
| 237 | 1972 |  |  |
| 238 | 1972 |  |  |
| 239 | 1973 |  |  |
| 240 | 1973 |  | Index volume |
| 241 | 1973 |  |  |
| 242 | 1973 |  |  |
| 243 | 1973 |  |  |
| 244 | 1973 |  |  |
| 245 | 1973 |  |  |
| 246 | 1973 |  |  |
| 247 | 1973 |  |  |
| 248 | 1973 |  |  |
| 249 | 1973 |  |  |
| 250 | 1973 |  | Index volume |
| 251 | 1973 |  |  |
| 252 | 1973 |  |  |
| 253 | 1973 |  |  |
| 254 | 1973 |  |  |
| 255 | 1973 |  |  |
| 256 | 1973 |  |  |
| 257 | 1973 |  |  |
| 258 | 1974 |  |  |
| 259 | 1974 |  |  |
| 260 | 1974 |  | Index volume |
| 261 | 1974 |  |  |
| 262 | 1974 |  |  |
| 263 | 1974 |  |  |
| 264 | 1974 |  |  |
| 265 | 1974 |  |  |
| 266 | 1974 |  |  |
| 267 | 1974 |  |  |
| 268 | 1974 |  |  |
| 269 | 1974 |  |  |
| 270 | 1974 |  | Index volume |
| 271 | 1974 |  |  |
| 272 | 1974 |  |  |
| 273 | 1974 |  |  |
| 274 | 1974 |  |  |
| 275 | 1974 |  |  |
| 276 | 1974 |  |  |
| 277 | 1974 |  |  |
| 278 | 1974 |  |  |
| 279 | 1974 |  |  |
| 280 | 1974 |  | Index volume |
| 281 | 1975 |  |  |
| 282 | 1975 |  |  |
| 283 | 1975 |  |  |
| 284 | 1975 |  |  |
| 285 | 1975 |  |  |
| 286 | 1975 |  |  |
| 287 | 1975 |  |  |
| 288 | 1975 |  |  |
| 289 | 1975 |  |  |
| 290 | 1975 |  | Index volume |
| 291 | 1975 |  |  |
| 292 | 1975 |  |  |
| 293 | 1975 |  |  |
| 294 | 1975 |  |  |
| 295 | 1975 |  |  |
| 296 | 1975 |  |  |
| 297 | 1975 |  |  |
| 298 | 1975 |  |  |
| 299 | 1975 |  |  |
| 300 | 1975 |  | Index volume |
| 301 | 1975 |  |  |
| 302 | 1975 |  |  |
| 303 | 1076 |  |  |
| 304 | 1976 |  |  |
| 305 | 1976 |  |  |
| 306 | 1976 |  |  |
| 307 | 1976 |  |  |
| 308 | 1976 |  |  |
| 309 | 1976 |  |  |
| 310 | 1976 |  | Index volume |
| 311 | 1976 |  |  |
| 312 | 1976 |  |  |
| 313 | 1976 |  |  |
| 314 | 1976 |  |  |
| 315 | 1976 |  |  |
| 316 | 1976 |  |  |
| 317 | 1976 |  |  |
| 318 | 1976 |  |  |
| 319 | 1976 |  |  |
| 320 | 1976 |  | Index volume |
| 321 | 1976 |  |  |
| 322 | 1976 |  |  |
| 323 | 1976 |  |  |
| 324 | 1976 |  |  |
| 325 | 1977 |  |  |
| 326 | 1977 |  |  |
| 327 | 1977 |  |  |
| 328 | 1977 |  |  |
| 329 | 1977 |  |  |
| 330 | 1977 |  | Index volume |
| 331 | 1977 |  |  |
| 332 | 1977 |  |  |
| 333 | 1977 |  |  |
| 334 | 1977 |  |  |
| 335 | 1977 |  |  |
| 336 | 1977 |  |  |
| 337 | 1977 |  |  |
| 338 | 1977 |  |  |
| 339 | 1977 |  |  |
| 340 | 1977 |  | Index volume |
| 341 | 1977 |  |  |
| 342 | 1977 |  |  |
| 343 | 1977 |  |  |
| 344 | 1977 |  |  |
| 345 | 1977 |  |  |
| 346 | 1977 |  |  |
| 347 | 1977 |  |  |
| 348 | 1977 |  |  |
| 349 | 1977 |  |  |
| 350 | 1977 |  | Index volume |
| 351 | 1978 |  |  |
| 352 | 1978 |  |  |
| 353 | 1978 |  |  |
| 354 | 1978 |  |  |
| 355 | 1978 |  |  |
| 356 | 1978 |  |  |
| 357 | 1978 |  |  |
| 358 | 1978 |  |  |
| 359 | 1978 |  |  |
| 360 | 1978 |  | Index volume |
| 361 | 1978 |  |  |
| 362 | 1978 |  |  |
| 363 | 1978 |  |  |
| 364 | 1978 |  |  |
| 365 | 1978 |  |  |
| 366 | 1978 |  |  |
| 367 | 1978 |  |  |
| 368 | 1978 |  |  |
| 369 | 1978 |  |  |
| 370 | 1978 |  | Index volume |
| 371 | 1978 |  |  |
| 372 | 1978 |  |  |
| 373 | 1978 |  |  |
| 374 | 1978 |  |  |
| 375 | 1978 |  |  |
| 376 | 1978 |  |  |
| 377 | 1979 |  |  |
| 378 | 1979 |  |  |
| 379 | 1979 |  |  |
| 380 | 1979 |  | Index volume |
| 381 | 1979 |  |  |
| 382 | 1979 |  |  |
| 383 | 1979 |  |  |
| 384 | 1979 |  |  |
| 385 | 1979 |  |  |
| 386 | 1979 |  |  |
| 387 | 1979 |  |  |
| 388 | 1979 |  |  |
| 389 | 1979 |  |  |
| 390 | 1979 |  | Index volume |
| 391 | 1979 |  |  |
| 392 | 1979 |  |  |
| 393 | 1979 |  |  |
| 394 | 1979 |  |  |
| 395 | 1979 |  |  |
| 396 | 1979 |  |  |
| 397 | 1979 |  |  |
| 398 | 1979 |  |  |
| 399 | 1979 |  |  |
| 400 | 1979 |  | Index volume |
| 401 | 1979 |  |  |
| 402 | 1979 |  |  |
| 403 | 1979 |  |  |
| 404 | 1980 |  |  |
| 405 | 1980 |  |  |
| 406 | 1980 |  |  |
| 407 | 1980 |  |  |
| 408 | 1980 |  |  |
| 409 | 1980 |  |  |
| 410 | 1980 |  | Index volume |
| 411 | 1980 |  |  |
| 412 | 1980 |  |  |
| 413 | 1980 |  |  |
| 414 | 1980 |  |  |
| 415 | 1980 |  |  |
| 416 | 1980 |  |  |
| 417 | 1980 |  |  |
| 418 | 1980 |  |  |
| 419 | 1980 |  |  |
| 420 | 1980 |  | Index volume |
| 421 | 1980 |  |  |
| 422 | 1980 |  |  |
| 423 | 1980 |  |  |
| 424 | 1980 |  |  |
| 425 | 1980 |  |  |
| 426 | 1980 |  |  |
| 427 | 1980 |  |  |
| 428 | 1980 |  |  |
| 429 | 1980 |  |  |
| 430 | 1981 |  | Index volume |
| 431 | 1981 |  |  |
| 432 | 1981 |  |  |
| 433 | 1981 |  |  |
| 434 | 1981 |  |  |
| 435 | 1981 |  |  |
| 436 | 1981 |  |  |
| 437 | 1981 |  |  |
| 438 | 1981 |  |  |
| 439 | 1981 |  |  |
| 440 | 1981 |  | Index volume |
| 441 | 1981 |  |  |
| 442 | 1981 |  |  |
| 443 | 1981 |  |  |
| 444 | 1981 |  |  |
| 445 | 1981 |  |  |
| 446 | 1981 |  |  |
| 447 | 1981 |  |  |
| 448 | 1981 |  |  |
| 449 | 1981 |  |  |
| 450 | 1981 |  | Index volume |
| 451 | 1981 |  |  |
| 452 | 1981 |  |  |
| 453 | 1981 |  |  |
| 454 | 1981 |  |  |
| 455 | 1981 |  |  |
| 456 | 1982 |  |  |
| 457 | 1982 |  |  |
| 458 | 1982 |  |  |
| 459 | 1982 |  |  |
| 460 | 1982 |  | Index volume |
| 461 | 1982 |  |  |
| 462 | 1982 |  |  |
| 463 | 1982 |  |  |
| 464 | 1982 |  |  |
| 465 | 1982 |  |  |
| 466 | 1982 |  |  |
| 467 | 1982 |  |  |
| 468 | 1982 |  |  |
| 469 | 1982 |  |  |
| 470 | 1982 |  | Index volume |
| 471 | 1982 |  |  |
| 472 | 1982 |  |  |
| 473 | 1982 |  |  |
| 474 | 1982 |  |  |
| 475 | 1982 |  |  |
| 476 | 1982 |  |  |
| 477 | 1982 |  |  |
| 478 | 1982 |  |  |
| 479 | 1982 |  |  |
| 480 | 1982 |  | Index volume |
| 481 | 1982 |  |  |
| 482 | 1982 |  |  |
| 483 | 1982 |  |  |
| 484 | 1983 |  |  |
| 485 | 1983 |  |  |
| 486 | 1983 |  |  |
| 487 | 1983 |  |  |
| 488 | 1983 |  |  |
| 489 | 1983 |  |  |
| 490 | 1983 |  | Index volume |
| 491 | 1983 |  |  |
| 492 | 1983 |  |  |
| 493 | 1983 |  |  |
| 494 | 1983 |  |  |
| 495 | 1983 |  |  |
| 496 | 1983 |  |  |
| 497 | 1983 |  |  |
| 498 | 1983 |  |  |
| 499 | 1983 |  |  |
| 500 | 1983 |  | Index volume |
| 501 | 1983 |  |  |
| 502 | 1983 |  |  |
| 503 | 1983 |  |  |
| 504 | 1983 |  |  |
| 505 | 1983 |  |  |
| 506 | 1983 |  |  |
| 507 | 1983 |  |  |
| 508 | 1983 |  |  |
| 509 | 1983 |  |  |
| 510 | 1983 |  | Index volume |
| 511 | 1984 |  |  |
| 512 | 1984 |  |  |
| 513 | 1984 |  |  |
| 514 | 1984 |  |  |
| 515 | 1984 |  |  |
| 516 | 1984 |  |  |
| 517 | 1984 |  |  |
| 518 | 1984 |  |  |
| 519 | 1984 |  |  |
| 520 | 1984 |  | Index volume |
| 521 | 1984 |  |  |
| 522 | 1984 |  |  |
| 523 | 1984 |  |  |
| 524 | 1984 |  |  |
| 525 | 1984 |  |  |
| 526 | 1984 |  |  |
| 527 | 1984 |  |  |
| 528 | 1984 |  |  |
| 529 | 1984 |  |  |
| 530 | 1984 |  | Index volume |
| 531 | 1984 |  |  |
| 532 | 1984 |  |  |
| 533 | 1984 |  |  |
| 534 | 1984 |  |  |
| 535 | 1984 |  |  |
| 536 | 1984 |  |  |
| 537 | 1985 |  |  |
| 538 | 1985 |  |  |
| 539 | 1985 |  |  |
| 540 | 1985 |  | Index volume |
| 541 | 1985 |  |  |
| 542 | 1985 |  |  |
| 543 | 1985 |  |  |
| 544 | 1985 |  |  |
| 545 | 1985 |  |  |
| 546 | 1985 |  |  |
| 547 | 1985 |  |  |
| 548 | 1985 |  |  |
| 549 | 1985 |  |  |
| 550 | 1985 |  | Index volume |
| 551 | 1985 |  |  |
| 552 | 1985 |  |  |
| 553 | 1985 |  |  |
| 554 | 1985 |  |  |
| 555 | 1985 |  |  |
| 556 | 1985 |  |  |
| 557 | 1985 |  |  |
| 558 | 1985 |  |  |
| 559 | 1985 |  |  |
| 560 | 1985 |  | Index volume |
| 561 | 1985 |  |  |
| 562 | 1985 |  |  |
| 563 | 1985 |  |  |
| 564 | 1986 |  |  |
| 565 | 1986 |  |  |
| 566 | 1986 |  |  |
| 567 | 1986 |  |  |
| 568 | 1986 |  |  |
| 569 | 1986 |  |  |
| 570 | 1986 |  | Index volume |
| 571 | 1986 |  |  |
| 572 | 1986 |  |  |
| 573 | 1986 |  |  |
| 574 | 1986 |  |  |
| 575 | 1986 |  |  |
| 576 | 1986 |  |  |
| 577 | 1986 |  |  |
| 578 | 1986 |  |  |
| 579 | 1986 |  |  |
| 580 | 1986 |  | Index volume |
| 581 | 1986 |  |  |
| 582 | 1986 |  |  |
| 583 | 1986 |  |  |
| 584 | 1986 |  |  |
| 585 | 1986 |  |  |
| 586 | 1986 |  |  |
| 587 | 1986 |  |  |
| 588 | 1986 |  |  |
| 589 | 1986 |  |  |
| 590 | 1986 |  | Index volume |
| 591 | 1987 |  |  |
| 592 | 1987 |  |  |
| 593 | 1987 |  |  |
| 594 | 1987 |  |  |
| 595 | 1987 |  |  |
| 596 | 1987 |  |  |
| 597 | 1987 |  |  |
| 598 | 1987 |  |  |
| 599 | 1987 |  |  |
| 600 | 1987 |  | Index volume |
| 601 | 1987 |  |  |
| 602 | 1987 |  |  |
| 603 | 1987 |  |  |
| 604 | 1987 |  |  |
| 605 | 1987 |  |  |
| 606 | 1987 |  |  |
| 607 | 1987 |  |  |
| 608 | 1987 |  |  |
| 609 | 1987 |  |  |
| 610 | 1987 |  | Index volume |
| 611 | 1987 |  |  |
| 612 | 1987 |  |  |
| 613 | 1987 |  |  |
| 614 | 1987 |  |  |
| 615 | 1987 |  |  |
| 616 | 1987 |  |  |
| 617 | 1988 |  |  |
| 618 | 1988 |  |  |
| 619 | 1988 |  |  |
| 620 | 1988 |  | Index volume |
| 621 | 1988 |  |  |
| 622 | 1988 |  |  |
| 623 | 1988 |  |  |
| 624 | 1988 |  |  |
| 625 | 1988 |  |  |
| 626 | 1988 |  |  |
| 627 | 1988 |  |  |
| 628 | 1988 |  |  |
| 629 | 1988 |  |  |
| 630 | 1988 |  | Index volume |
| 631 | 1988 |  |  |
| 632 | 1988 |  |  |
| 633 | 1988 |  |  |
| 634 | 1988 |  |  |
| 635 | 1988 |  |  |
| 636 | 1988 |  |  |
| 637 | 1988 |  |  |
| 638 | 1988 |  |  |
| 639 | 1988 |  |  |
| 640 | 1988 |  | Index volume |
| 641 | 1988 |  |  |
| 642 | 1988 |  |  |
| 643 | 1988 |  |  |
| 644 | 1989 |  |  |
| 645 | 1989 |  |  |
| 646 | 1989 |  |  |
| 647 | 1989 |  |  |
| 648 | 1989 |  |  |
| 649 | 1989 |  |  |
| 650 | 1989 |  | Index volume |
| 651 | 1989 |  |  |
| 652 | 1989 |  |  |
| 653 | 1989 |  |  |
| 654 | 1989 |  |  |
| 655 | 1989 |  |  |
| 656 | 1989 |  |  |
| 657 | 1989 |  |  |
| 658 | 1989 |  |  |
| 659 | 1989 |  |  |
| 660 | 1989 |  | Index volume |
| 661 | 1989 |  |  |
| 662 | 1989 |  |  |
| 663 | 1989 |  |  |
| 664 | 1989 |  |  |
| 665 | 1989 |  |  |
| 666 | 1989 |  |  |
| 667 | 1989 |  |  |
| 668 | 1989 |  |  |
| 669 | 1989 |  |  |
| 670 | 1989 |  | Index volume |
| 671 | 1990 |  |  |
| 672 | 1990 |  |  |
| 673 | 1990 |  |  |
| 674 | 1990 |  |  |
| 675 | 1990 |  |  |
| 676 | 1990 |  |  |
| 677 | 1990 |  |  |
| 678 | 1990 |  |  |
| 679 | 1990 |  |  |
| 680 | 1990 |  | Index volume |
| 681 | 1990 |  |  |
| 682 | 1990 |  |  |
| 683 | 1990 |  |  |
| 684 | 1990 |  |  |
| 685 | 1990 |  |  |
| 686 | 1990 |  |  |
| 687 | 1990 |  |  |
| 688 | 1990 |  |  |
| 689 | 1990 |  |  |
| 690 | 1990 |  | Index volume |
| 691 | 1990 |  |  |
| 692 | 1990 |  |  |
| 693 | 1990 |  |  |
| 694 | 1990 |  |  |
| 695 | 1990 |  |  |
| 696 | 1990 |  |  |
| 697 | 1991 |  |  |
| 698 | 1991 |  |  |
| 699 | 1991 |  |  |
| 700 | 1991 |  | Index volume |
| 701 | 1991 |  |  |
| 702 | 1991 |  |  |
| 703 | 1991 |  |  |
| 704 | 1991 |  |  |
| 705 | 1991 |  |  |
| 706 | 1991 |  |  |
| 707 | 1991 |  |  |
| 708 | 1991 |  |  |
| 709 | 1991 |  |  |
| 710 | 1991 |  | Index volume |
| 711 | 1991 |  |  |
| 712 | 1991 |  |  |
| 713 | 1991 |  |  |
| 714 | 1991 |  |  |
| 715 | 1991 |  |  |
| 716 | 1991 |  |  |
| 717 | 1991 |  |  |
| 718 | 1991 |  |  |
| 719 | 1991 |  |  |
| 720 | 1991 |  | Index volume |
| 721 | 1991 |  |  |
| 722 | 1991 |  |  |
| 723 | 1991 |  |  |

Comment: The very large table here takes up a huge amount of space on this page. I wonder if it can be compressed or hidden in some way.

Answer (score 4):

The numbering is sequential in the order in which a review is entered, so not strictly tied to a particular year of publication. For example, [volume 1430](https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A1430.*) has mainly papers published in 2019 and 2020, but it also includes papers from 2016,2017, and 2018.
Here is a rough guide of the correspondence between volume number and publication date range:

- 2020-     (vols 1431- )
- 2015-2020 (vols. 1301-1430)
- 2010-2015 (vols. 1191-1300)
- 2005-2010 (vols. 1051-1190
- 1999-2005 (vols. 913-1050)
- 1995-1999 (vols. 826-912)
- 1990-1995 (vols. 701-824)
- 1985-1989 (vols. 551-699)
- 1970-1984 (vols. 201-549)
- 1931-1969 (vols. 1-199)